# Action mode is not applied to toolbar (being used as action bar), when using with ListView CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL

Tags: android

In my project I'm replacing the Action Bar with a Tool Bar. I inherited my theme from Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar and called setActionBar from my Activity's onCreate to pass the toolbar. So far so good. The problem is when I use a ListView with CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL. The action mode appears on top of the Too Bar, where the actual Action Bar would've reside, had I not removed it with NoActionBar theme.

[image: Without action mode]
[image: With action mode]

Is there something I need to configure in the ListView? Or the MultiChoiceModeListener?

Here is my super trivial code for activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionMode.Callback, AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {

static final ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Apple", "Ball", "Cat", "Dog", "Elephant", "Flower"));
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

    lv = findViewById(R.id.wordList);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, values);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_normal, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "This is a test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_active, menu);
    mode.setTitle("Go CAPS!");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    turnWordsToUppercase();
    mode.finish();

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    lv.clearChoices();
    lv.requestLayout();
}

@Override
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
}

void turnWordsToUppercase() {
    //Logic for turning words to uppercase
}
```

}

Here is my theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>` to your app theme

Comment: I added it to the app theme, still it's the same. Updated my post to reflect this.